# Updating properties of points within polygons based on a spatial setting

Tags: r, polygon, spatial, point

Assume I have polygons and points that look like this:

```
library(sf)
library(sp)

####Create minimum working example data####
n_rows <- 10  # Number of rows of rectangles
n_cols <- 10  # Number of columns of rectangles
rect_width <- 1  # Width of each rectangle
rect_height <- 1  # Height of each rectangle

#Initialize a list to store rectangle polygons
rectangles <- list()

#Create rectangles and add them to the list with gaps
#Create rectangles and add them to the list
for (i in 1:n_rows) {
  for (j in 1:n_cols) {
    #Define the coordinates for the four corners of each rectangle
    x_coords <- c((j - 1) * rect_width, j * rect_width, j * rect_width, (j - 1) * rect_width, (j - 1) * rect_width)
    y_coords <- c((i - 1) * rect_height, (i - 1) * rect_height, i * rect_height, i * rect_height, (i - 1) * rect_height)
    
    #Combine the coordinates into a matrix
    rect_coords <- cbind(x_coords, y_coords)
    
    #Create a polygon from the coordinates and add it to the list
    rectangles[[length(rectangles) + 1]] <- st_polygon(list(rect_coords))
  }
}

#Create an sf object representing the rectangles with gaps
polygons_sf <- st_sf(geometry = st_sfc(rectangles))

polygons_sf$ID <- 1:100  # Add an ID column to represent each rectangle

#Generate random points within each rectangle
set.seed(123)  # for reproducibility
points <- st_sample(polygons_sf, size = 100)
points_sf <- st_sf(geometry = st_sfc(points))

#Generate a vector of values 
Depth <- as.integer(runif(100, min = 1, max = 5))

#Add the new column to random_points
points_sf$Z <- Depth
```

[image: Points and polygons]

For the points in each polygon I want to do some calculations which change the depth of the points. For the calculations I need to collect all the points within a radius of the average depth of the points within the polygon around the polygon. Lets do it for polygon #45 for example:

```
# Function to calculate average Z value for points within a polygon
calculate_average_Z <- function(polygon, points) {
  points_in_polygon <- st_intersection(points, polygon)  
  if (nrow(points_in_polygon) == 0) {
    return(NA)  # No points in the polygon
  }
  avg_Z <- mean(points_in_polygon$Z)
  return(avg_Z)
}

#Do select points in a buffer around polygon #45
polygon <- polygons_sf[45, ]
    
avg_Z <- calculate_average_Z(polygon, points_sf)
    
#if (is.na(avg_Z)) {
 # next 
#}
    
buffer_distance <- avg_Z  
buffered_polygon <- st_buffer(polygon, dist = buffer_distance)
    
# Select points within the buffered area
points_in_buffered_area <- st_filter(points_sf, buffered_polygon)
```

[image: Buffered Polygon and selected points]

Now I want to calculate some stuff based on properties of the polygon and X/Y/Z of the points within the buffered area, which will result in changing the depth of the points within the polygon:

```
##For the real calculations I need X and Y as columns
#point_coordinates <- st_coordinates(points_in_buffered_area)
#points_in_buffered_area$X <- point_coordinates[, "X"]
#points_in_buffered_area$Y <- point_coordinates[, "Y"]

#while loop for changing depth of the points     
    while (TRUE) {
      Depth_t <- 4
      ##here there is in reality a very complicated function
      #that uses the properies of the polygon and the X/Y/Z of the points as input
      #to calculate the depth needed at this location. 
      Depth <- avg_Z
      
    if (Depth>= Depth_t) {
      break  # Exit the loop if the condition is met
    }
    
    avg_Z <- avg_Z + 1
    }
```

Now I want to update the Z value for the points within the polygon in the original points_sf dataframe:

```
new_Z <- data.frame(X = points_in_buffered_area$X, Y = points_in_buffered_area$Y, new_Z = avg_Z, geom=points_in_buffered_area$geom)
# Convert the data frame to an sf object
new_Z_values <- st_as_sf(new_Z, crs = st_crs(points_sf))

# Select points within original polygon
new_Z_to_use <- st_intersection(new_Z_values, polygon)
new_Z_to_use <- new_Z_to_use[, -c(1,2,4)]
#print(new_Z_to_use)
# Join new Z values to points_sf and update Z values
points_sf <- st_join(points_sf, new_Z_to_use, by = c("geometry"= "geometry"))
points_sf$Z <- ifelse(!is.na(points_sf$new_Z), points_sf$new_Z, points_sf$Z)

#delete not needed column
points_sf <- points_sf[, -2]
```

This works very well when I do it manually as now the points within the polygon #45 have now updated Z values. However I want this to be automated and have tried the following:

```
# Create a vector of polygon indices
polygon_indices <- 1:nrow(polygons_sf)

# Initialize a list to store results
results_list <- vector("list", length = length(polygon_indices))

#function to loop through all polygons:
process_polygons <- function(indices) {
  points_sf<-points_sf
  for (i in indices) {
      polygon <- polygons_sf[i, ]
      avg_Z <- calculate_average_Z(polygon, points_sf)
    
      if (is.na(avg_Z)) {
         next
      }
    
      buffer_distance <- avg_Z  
    
      buffered_polygon <- st_buffer(polygon, dist = buffer_distance)
    
      # Select points within the buffered area
      points_in_buffered_area <- st_filter(points_sf, buffered_polygon)
      point_coordinates <- st_coordinates(points_in_buffered_area)
      points_in_buffered_area$X <- point_coordinates[, "X"]
      points_in_buffered_area$Y <- point_coordinates[, "Y"]
    
      while (TRUE) {
        Depth_t <- 4
        ##here there is in reality a very complicated function
        #that uses the properies of the polygon and the X/Y/Z of the points as input
        #to calculate the depth needed at this location. 
        Depth <- avg_Z
   
      if (Depth>= Depth_t) {
        break  # Exit the loop if the condition is met
      }
    
      avg_Z <- avg_Z + 1
      }
    
      new_Z <- data.frame(X = points_in_buffered_area$X, Y = points_in_buffered_area$Y, new_Z = avg_Z, geom=points_in_buffered_area$geom)
    
      # Convert the data frame to an sf object
      new_Z_values <- st_as_sf(new_Z, crs = st_crs(points_sf))
    
      # Select points within original polygon
      new_Z_to_use <- st_intersection(new_Z_values, polygon)
      new_Z_to_use <- new_Z_to_use[, -c(1,2,4)]
      #print(new_Z_to_use)
      # Join new Z values to points_sf and update Z values
      points_sf <- st_join(points_sf, new_Z_to_use, by = c("geometry"= "geometry"))
      points_sf$Z <- ifelse(!is.na(points_sf$new_Z), points_sf$new_Z, points_sf$Z)
      points_sf <- points_sf[, -2]
      # Store the result in the list
      result <- c(avg_Z)
     #print(result)
     return(result)
  }
}  

results_list <- lapply(polygon_indices, process_polygons)
```

I feel that this *should* work, but it does not update the original points_sf dataframe with the updated Z values. Each time a new polygon is buffered it should take the new Z values of the previous polygon into account, but now this does not happen. Any idea how to solve this (efficiently)?

Sorry for the long post, but I tried to make it as comprehensive and workable as possible.

Comment: I didn't study this thoroughly but the problem seems to be that you are expecting `process_polygons()` to make changes to objects in the global environment (`points_sf`) which it won't. The function only works with a local copy of `points_sf` and once it exits, all changes made to it are forgotten. You can make it write to an object in a parent environment by using `<<-` instead of `<-` but be careful with this, functions with such side effects can make you code more difficult to understand and maintain.

Comment: Thanks, that seems indeed to help! 

This is the code that now works 
`
process_polygons <- function(indices) {
 #points_sf<-points_sf
  for (i in indices) {...
  points_sf <<- points_sf[, -2]
   return(result)
  }
}  
`

Comment: To @RobertHacken caution on `<<-`, you could `process_polygons(indices, points) {` and return(list(points=points & whatever else you're returning.... Good write up.